# Capturing dynamically generated input tag through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an application where I have an add more button and I need to use jquery autocomplete on that dynamically generated input and I am trying to use keyup as the event to initiate autocomplete

my HTML Code

```
<div class="form-group" id="medicineTable">
                            <div class="col-sm-8 selectContainer">
                                <input name="OTCtext[]" id="OTCtext" class="form-control medicinefind"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4 selectContainer">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Qts" value="1"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group" id="medicineTableTemp">
                            <div class="col-sm-8 selectContainer">
                                <input name="OTCtext[]" id="OTCtext" class="form-control medicinefind">
                                <input type="hidden" id="hiddenValue" value="0">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4 selectContainer">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Qts" value="1"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

my js code

```
$('.selectContainer').on('keyup', 'input.medicinefind', function(){
           alert('clicked');
        });
```

I am not able to catch the dynamic inout fields with this so please assist

Comment: I think yo have selected wrong parent! Try `$('#medicineTable').on('keyup', 'input.medicinefind', function(){
           alert('clicked');
        });`

Comment: Which input is the one being dynamically generated? What is generating it? Can you initialize the autocomplete on it at the same time you dynamically generate it?

Comment: Thanks Rayon it worked.. If you would like to post this as an answer I will accept that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [**`Event delegation`**](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

In your example, you have selected wrong element as parent!

```
$('#medicineTable').on('keyup', 'input.medicinefind', function(){ alert('clicked'); });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to initiate it after DOM populates or once elements gets added to DOM. also it will be better if you could share your working sample link that will help me to help you.